# Android Google Play - SMS and Call LOG issue

Tags: android

Today a message appeared in Google play in one of my android apps, that it violates the Google's SMS or Call Log policy.

But that app is just simple listview of images and text, NO permissions are asked ever!

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AesirActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SingleitemView" />
    <activity android:name=".VanirActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".BytostiActivity" />
</application>
```

I don't understand what is happening as I don't use any SMS or Call in my app.

Dependencies from gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Comment: Maybe some of libraries you use require it. Post your complete Android manifest and the list of dependencies.

Comment: I updated my answer with dependencies I use. The manifest is as you see above. The app doesn't use anything else - it is just a simple listview from array - images and text.

Comment: No. What is in your manifest file is not necessary what is in final build

Comment: I checked the build log but there is nothing special added to manifest after final build. However today I do not see that message anymore in Google play. Seems it was some bug, because I have NO other permissions or libraries. I created many other apps on the exact same base. And do not mark this theme as duplicate, as my question was not where to find permissions after build, but why is the message in google play if I have NO such libraries or permissions in my app